# Is there a way to force mutually exclusive function parameters in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optional-parameters, keyword-argument, optional-arguments

Consider:

```
def foobar(*, foo, bar):
    if foo:
        print('foo', end="")
    if bar:
        print('bar', end="")
    if foo and bar:
        print('No bueno', end='')  # I want this to be impossible
    if not foo and not bar:
        print('No bueno', end='')  # I want this to be impossible
    print('')


foobar(foo='bar')  # I want to pass inspection
foobar(bar='foo')  # I want to pass inspection
foobar(foo='bar', bar='foo')  # I want to fail inspection
foobar()  # I want to fail inspection
```

Is there a way to set up a function so that way calling it only passes inspection when just one of foo or bar is being passed, without manually checking inside the function?

Comment: `foo` and `bar` are keyword-only parameters in that `foobar` definition, not optional parameters. (I've seen a lot of people make the opposite mistake, but this is the first time I've seen anyone mix things up in this direction.)

Comment: Yes I'm aware that they are not optional right now. I was wondering if there is a way to make it so that way to pass inspection when calling `foobar`, you could only pass one of foo or bar.

Comment: Make them both named with a setting to none and check that?

Comment: While that would work on making it fail, it still passes inspection, and so someone wouldn't realise something is wrong until running the code. This is where I'm coming from.

Comment: What do you mean by "it still passes inspection"? What sort of inspection do you want to catch this? Some specific automated tool? Code review by a programmer of a certain Python experience level?

Comment: Basically I want pycharm to give me a warning before I run the code, and I want the python to raise an error when trying to enter the function.

Answer (score 7):

Syntactically no. However it's relatively easy to do this using a decorator:

```
from functools import wraps

def mutually_exclusive(keyword, *keywords):
    keywords = (keyword,)+keywords
    def wrapper(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            if sum(k in keywords for k in kwargs) != 1:
                raise TypeError('You must specify exactly one of {}'.format(', '.join(keywords)))
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return inner
    return wrapper
```

Used as:

```
>>> @mutually_exclusive('foo', 'bar')
... def foobar(*, foo=None, bar=None):
...     print(foo, bar)
... 
>>> foobar(foo=1)
1 None
>>> foobar(bar=1)
None 1
>>> foobar(bar=1, foo=2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in inner
TypeError: You must specify exactly one of foo, bar
>>> foobar()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in inner
TypeError: You must specify exactly one of foo, bar
```

The decorator ignores positionals and keyword arguments not included in the list given:

```
>>> @mutually_exclusive('foo', 'bar')
... def foobar(a,b,c, *, foo=None, bar=None, taz=None):
...     print(a,b,c,foo,bar,taz)
... 
>>> foobar(1,2,3, foo=4, taz=5)
1 2 3 4 None 5
>>> foobar(1,2,3, foo=4, bar=5,taz=6)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in inner
TypeError: You must specify exactly one of foo, bar
```

If the arguments might be "optional" (i.e. you may specify at most one of those keyword arguments, but you may also omit all of them) just change `!= 1` to `<= 1` or `in (0,1)` as you prefer.

If you replace `1` with a number `k` you generalize the decorator to accept exactly (or at most) `k` of the specified arguments from the set you provided.

This however will not help PyCharm in anyway. As far as I know currently it's simply impossible to tell an IDE what you want.

---

The above decorator has a little "bug": it considers `foo=None` as if you passed a value for `foo` since it appears in the `kwargs` list. Usually you'd expect that passing the default value should behave identically as if you did not specify the argument at all.

Fixing this properly would require to inspect `func` inside `wrapper` to lookup the defaults and change `k in keywords` with something like `k in keywords and kwargs[k] != defaults[k]`.

Comment: This is a very pythonic way of achieving the desired results. Though I would suggest `ValueError` or `RuntimeError`in place of `TypeError`. Personal preference, I suppose.

Comment: @PMende I chose `TypeError` because typically the errors raised when you provide the wrong arguments raise `TypeError` (e.g. `def f(a): pass` then `f(b=1)` raises `TypeError: f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'b'`. So I believe `TypeError` is more consistent in this case since we are simulating a special *signature* for the function... But then this is an opinion.

Comment: Would this also work for a constructor of a class? Think of the canonical example of a circle class for which objects would be generated using a midpoint and either (exclusively) a radius or a diameter....

Comment: And for a python dataclass ?

Comment: @GertVdE You can manually define the `__init__` and put the decorator on it (given that you work with mutually excusive arguments chances are you might want some other custom logic anyway). If you don't want to write your own custom `__init__` chances are you have to use metaclasses. You should lookup some tutorial on python3 metaclasses.

Answer (score 1):

The standard library uses a simple runtime check for this:

```
def foobar(*, foo=None, bar=None):
    if (foo is None) == (bar is None):
        raise ValueError('Exactly one of `foo` and `bar` must be provided')
```

Answer (score 0):

In short: no you cannot do that.

The closest you can get to that might be the use of an assertion:

```
def foobar(foo=None, bar=None):
    assert bool(foo) != bool(bar)

foobar(foo='bar')             # Passes
foobar(bar='foo')             # Passes
foobar(foo='bar', bar='foo')  # Raises an AssertionError
foobar()                      # Raises an AssertionError
```

The combination of the `bool` conversions and the `!=` will make a logical XOR.

Be careful with assertions though; they can be disabled. It's fine if your check is required during development only.

Comment: Be careful checking for boolean equality instead of `is None`. If only one falsey parameter was passed this would still raise an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You could refactor slightly and take *two* non-optional parameters that together provide *one* value:

```
def foobar(name, value):
    if name == 'foo':
        foo = value
    elif name == 'bar':
        bar = value
    else:
        raise ValueError()
```

That way it's impossible to pass two foo or bar values. PyCharm would also warn you if you added extra parameters.